Problem containing sum of product of Binomial coefficients
I was solving a problem when I came across the following expression, and despite various attempts, I was unable to simplify it. I am trying to simplify the expression $$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}\binom{m}{i}$$
where it is given that $n<m$. My approach so far has been to expand $(1+x)^n(x+1)^m$ however that did not work, and instead resulted in $\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}^2=\binom{2n}{n}$ which seems like a special case of what I desire to calculate.
This expression appeared with $n=2024$ and $m=2034$, while solving the following problem with Lagrange's identity:

Find the largest integer $k$ such that $2^k$ divides $S$ given
$$S=\sum_{0\le i<j\le 2024}\left[\binom{2024}{i}\binom{2034}{j}-\binom{2024}{j}\binom{2034}{i}\right]^2$$

I know I should use the $\nu_2$ function but I am trying to get a simplified form of the expression before I do that. It is quite easy to see that the sum can be rewritten as
$$2S=\sum_{i=0}^{2024}\sum_{j=0}^{2024}\left[\binom{2024}{i}\binom{2034}{j}-\binom{2024}{j}\binom{2034}{i}\right]^2$$
since $f(i,j)=f(j,i)$ and $f(i,i)=0$ if $f(i,j)$ denotes the summand in the original expression. However, I do not know how I can simplify this expression further.
Using Lagrange's Identity, we can simplify it down to $$\binom{4048}{2024}\sum_{i=0}^{2024}\binom{2034}{i}^2-\sum_{i=0}^{2024}\binom{2024}{i}\binom{2034}{i}$$
Here, we run into the expression that was mentioned in the beginning of the post.
This is a problem from a practice paper for a Round 1 Qualifier for IMO in India. Source: https://www.agamjeet.com/ioqm-mock-donut-1-blog P23.

Are you sure an IOQM contestant would be familar with the Lagrange identity you used?

What other alternative methods do you suggest to solve the problem?

@wolqz you just need to expand out the terms using $(a+b)^2$ etc


My approach so far has been to expand (1+x)n(x+1)m however that did not work

This actually works, and results in Vandermonde's identity, that is:
$$
{m+n \choose r}=\sum_{k=0}^r{m \choose k}{n \choose r-k}
$$
Therefore, your expression can be simplified as:
$$
\begin{align} \sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}\binom{m}{i} &= \sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{n-i}\binom{m}{i} \\ &= \binom{m+n}{n} \end{align}
$$

Let us define $a_i = \binom{2024}i$ and $b_i = \binom{2034}i$.
$$\begin{align}
2S &= \sum_{i=0}^{2024} \sum_{j=0}^{2024} (a_ib_j - a_jb_i)^2 \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{2024} \sum_{j=0}^{2024} a_i^2b_j^2 + a_j^2b_i^2 - 2a_ia_jb_ib_j \\
&= 2\sum_{i=0}^{2024} \sum_{j=0}^{2024} a_i^2b_j^2 - 2\left(\sum_{i=0}^{2024} a_ib_i\right)^2\\
&= 2\sum_{i=0}^{2024} a_i^2\sum_{j=0}^{2024} b_j^2 - 2\left(\sum_{i=0}^{2024} \binom{2024}i\binom{2034}{i}\right)^2 \\
&= 2\sum_{i=0}^{2024} a_i^2\sum_{j=0}^{2024} b_j^2 - 2\binom{4058}{2024}^2\\
&= 2\binom{4048}{2024}\sum_{j=0}^{2024} b_j^2 - 2\binom{4058}{2024}^2 \\
&= 2\binom{4048}{2024}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{2034} b_j^2 - \sum_{j=0}^{9} b_j^2\right) - 2\binom{4058}{2024}^2 \\
&= 2\binom{4048}{2024}\left(\binom{4068}{2034} - \sum_{j=0}^{9} b_j^2\right) - 2\binom{4058}{2024}^2 \\
S &= \underbrace{\binom{4048}{2024}}_{T_1}\left(\underbrace{\binom{4068}{2034}}_{T_2} - \underbrace{\sum_{j=0}^{9} b_j^2}_{T_3}\right) - \underbrace{\binom{4058}{2024}^2}_{T_4}
\end{align}$$
At this point I can't see a simplification and the following relies heavily on some calculations. Maybe these calculations can be circumvented and a better method be adopted. I've tried that without much luck.
Noting Legendre's formula, we see: $v_2(T_4) = 2(v_2(4058!) - v_2(2024!) - v_2(2034!))=2(6) = 12$; $v_2(T_2) = v_2(4068!) - 2v_2(2034!) = 8$; and finally $v_2(T_1)=v_2(4048!) - 2v_2(2024!) = 7$. One can also work out $v_2(b_i^2)$ for $i\in \{0,1,2\cdots 9\}$ to find that all of the $b_i^2$ are even with powers $v_2(b_i^2)\geq 2$ except $b_0$ and $b_2$. Calculating their values adding their squares shows that $v_2(b_0^2 + b_2^2) = 1$. It follows that $v_2(T_3) = v_2(2k') = 1$ where $k'$ is odd. Thus, $v_2(T_2-T_3) = v_2(2^8x' - 2k') = 1$ where $x'$ is odd. Thus, $v_2(T_1(T_2-T_3)) = 2^8$ and so $v_2(T_1(T_2-T_3) - T_4) = v_2(S) = 8$.
Therefore $\max k$ such that $2^k \mid S$ is $\boxed 8$.
